# iOS - Is it possible to reset a label/textView to their initial state defined in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, iphone

In my application I have four buttons and a few text labels. The text in the labels are defined through interface builder. I'm bad with words so I hope the code below is clear enough to point out what I'm trying to do.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Default view loaded as defined in Interface Builder

}

- (IBAction)button_1_Pressed:(id)sender {

    // Programmatically Change text in Labels
}

- (IBAction)button_2_pressed:(id)sender {

    // Programmatically Change text in labels

}

- (IBAction)button_3_pressed:(id)sender {

    // Programmatically Change text in labels
}

- (IBAction)button_4_pressed:(id)sender {

    // Change text in labels back to the values when the view first loaded.
    // That is, to the text defined in Interface builder instead of changing 
    // it back programmatically. 
}
```

Or perhaps is there a way to reset/'restart' the view when button 4 is pressed?

Comment: The best way to achieve this is using the strings for storing the label original text. When your application starts store the label text in strings and do whatever you want to do, And when you need those previous values you have them in the strings, So simply restore those values in your `button_$_pressed` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it, use it.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    self.originalText = self.textField.text;
}

-(void)restore {
    self.textField.text = self.originalText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You `Reload` the view to get the origional Text.